# Is it possible to change the language displayed by the TextClock view in xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am using `TextClock` to display which day and which date it is.

**Is it possible to change the default language (english) of TextClock?**

```
        <TextClock
            android:id="@+id/date"
            style="@style/DateStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:format12Hour="EEEE\n MMMM d"
            android:format24Hour="EEEEd\n MMMM"/>
```

**Display:**

[image: Display]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with writing a custom `TextClock` and setting `Locale` in it. Try this:

```
public class MyTextClock extends android.widget.TextClock {

    public MyTextClock(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setLocaleDateFormat();
    }

    public MyTextClock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setLocaleDateFormat();
    }

    public MyTextClock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setLocaleDateFormat();
    }

    private void setLocaleDateFormat() {
        // You can change language from here
        Locale currentLocale = new Locale("en");
        Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), currentLocale);

        String dayName = cal.getDisplayName(cal.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, currentLocale);
        String monthName = cal.getDisplayName(cal.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, currentLocale);

        this.setFormat12Hour("'" + dayName + "'\n'" + monthName + "' dd");
        this.setFormat24Hour("'" + dayName + "'\n'" + monthName + "' dd");
    }
}
```

Implement this custom `TextClock` to your layout like that:

```
<com.your.package.MyTextClock
    android:id="@+id/date"
    style="@style/DateStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
```

Here you go. Good luck.

Comment: How do I call this class from my main activity? It's been a long time:(

Comment: using this the clock is not updated automatically. How to solve this.